# Adding this decorator @OneToMany to a Nestjs entity causes the following error, "Cannot find module 'src/books/books/book.entity'"

Tags: typescript, entity, one-to-many, nestjs, typeorm

I'm working on NestJs for now and I'm trying to make a demo containing two models Book and Author, it all works great till I try to define the relation so whenever I do annotate the books attribute in the Author model with @OneToMany() the application throws an error Error: Cannot find module 'src/books/books/book.entity'

```
@Entity('AUTHOR')
export class Author {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({name: 'ID'})
    @ApiModelProperty()
    id: number;
    @Column({name: 'NAME'})
    @ApiModelProperty()
    name: string;
    // ----------------------
    @OneToMany(type => Book, book => book.id)
    @JoinTable()
    @ApiModelProperty()
    books: Book[];
}
// *************************************
@Entity('BOOK')
export class Book extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({name: 'ID'})
    @ApiModelProperty()
    id: number;
    @Column({name: 'TITLE'})
    @ApiModelProperty()
    title: string;
    @Column({name: 'ISBN'})
    @ApiModelProperty()
    ISBN: number;
}
```

Error: Cannot find module 'src/books/books/book.entity'

Comment: Is that the correct path to your `Book` entity? What does your folder set up look like? What about the `import` statement? It's hard to tell what's going on with just this small snippet.

Comment: Check the paths are correct.  Make sure that you are setting up typeorm properly (`TypeormModule.forRoot` and `TypeormModule.forFeature`).  You should add `ManyToOne` to the `Book` entity field `author: Author` and do something like `@OneToMany(() => Book, book => book.author)` and `@ManyToOne(() => Author, author => author.books)`

Comment: Had the same problem, paths to the entities were not correct https://stackoverflow.com/a/54049216/1775703